# Cannot encode G722 with avenc_g722 for Gstreamer application: Caught SIGSEGV

Tags: gstreamer, codec, segmentation-fault, libav, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to stream audio in G722 codec with gstreamer-1.0.
When I use following commands, SIGSEGV has occured.

> tx: gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device="hw:0" ! decodebin ! audioconvert
>   ! audioresample ! avenc_g722 ! fakesink

results:

> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps
>   = "audio/x-raw\,\ format\=(string)S16LE\,\ layout\=(string)interleaved\,\ rate\=(int)44100\,\
>   channels\=(int)2\,\ channel-mask\=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003"
>
> Caught SIGSEGV
>
> #0  0x76d28c20 in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
>
> #1  0x00000000 in ?? () 
>   0:00:02.291262125   957  0x1122d50 WARN
>                    alsa gstalsasrc.c:868:xrun_recovery: xrun recovery -32:
>   Broken pipe Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch-1.0 957' to continue
>   debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.

I checked gdb, but the result is as follows.

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread
>   library, thread debugging will not be available.
>
> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread
>   library, thread debugging will not be available. 0x76c9bc20 in poll ()
>   from /lib/libc.so.6

What can I do to solve this? Is avenc_g722 has a bug?

Are there any g722 encoder?
I only know ffenc_g722 but I think gst-ffmpeg is only for gstreamer-0.10, so I cannot use it.

Environment:

OS: yocto Morty
CPU: imx6ull (16bit)

Comment: Doesn't crash on amd64 (gstreamer 1.8.3).

Comment: thank you for commenting. Hmm... avenc_g722 may not work with 16 bit CPU...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding audioparse something like below:

> gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device="hw:0" ! audioparse ! decodebin !
>   audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_g722 ! fakesink dump=true

Comment: just bumped into https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707040 , are you using the latest gstreamer release or the old one ?

Comment: the result of gst-launch-1.0 --version is as follows.

gst-launch-1.0 version 1.8.3
GStreamer 1.8.3
Unknown package origin

Comment: Worth updating your gstreamer and testing it back again!

Comment: Oh, the latest version is 1.12.4! I used provided BSP recipes and I did not check it. I will try the latest one! thank you again. I will report after trying!

Comment: Hi, I checked with 1.12.3 and the SIGSEGV error has gone. Thank you very much!!